# Outlook MAPI IConverterSession->MAPIToMIMEStm returns the different stream output with or without PR_BODY when converting the same MSG File To EML

Tags: outlook, mapi

When trying to convert the MSG-File stored with Microsoft Outlook 15.0 to EML using Outlook 2016 MAPIToMIMEStm API returns different stream output when this API is called multiple times without restarting the process.
The Java application loads the JNI dll which converts the messages stored in the .pst file into .eml files.

.eml file content->

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
boundary="----=_NextPart_000_0004_01D9F13A.C9638500"
X-Mailer: Microsoft Outlook 15.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
<PR_BODY>
...
```

The code snippet is given below.

```
MAPIINIT_0 MAPIINIT= { 0, MAPI_MULTITHREAD_NOTIFICATIONS};
HRESULT hr = MAPIInitialize(&MAPIINIT);

//Extract IMessage from the IMAPIFolder 
IConverterSession* pConverterSession = NULL;    
hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_IConverterSession, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                                  IID_IConverterSession, (void **) &pConverterSession);
                                  
LPSTREAM pStream = NULL;
hr = OpenStreamOnFile(MAPIAllocateBuffer, MAPIFreeBuffer, STGM_CREATE |
        STGM_READWRITE, const_cast<char*>(mbFilename.c_str()), NULL, &pStream);
        
ULONG flags = CCSF_SMTP | CCSF_INCLUDE_BCC | CCSF_8BITHEADERS;
hr = pConverterSession->MAPIToMIMEStm(pMessage, pStream, flags);
//pStream->Stat() shows the stream output of length 4285 which includes the PR_BODY of the IMessage.

pStream->Commit(0);
pStream->Release();
pConverterSession->Release();
MAPIUninitialize();
```

If the same code is called again without restarting the application then pStream->Stat() shows the stream output of length 4228 excluding the PR_BODY of the IMessage. The MAPIToMIMEStm excludes the PR_BODY of the IMessage during conversion.

If the Java application is restarted, then pStream->Stat() shows that stream output of length 4285 which includes the PR_BODY of the IMessage.

What could be the reasons for this behavior of Outlook MAPI pConverterSession->MAPIToMIMEStm()?

Comment: Where does `pMessage` come from?

Comment: The IMessage* pMessage is extracted from the IMAPIFolder->OpenEntry() of the .pst file.

Comment: Is only plain text body missing? Do you still see HTML body?

Comment: Only plain text body is missing. HTML body is present.

Comment: Can you successfully retrieve PR_BODY_W using `HrGetOneProp`?

Comment: Yes. I verified that PR_BODY_W can be retrieved using HrGetOneProp from the IMessage. Is there a way to get the debug logs of the MAPIToMIMEStm API to know which cases MAPIToMIMEStm is not calling HrGetOneProp to get PR_BODY_W?

Comment: No, there is no logging. Try to comment out `MAPIUninitialize` so that the MAPI system stays initialized.

Comment: This issue is not resolved even after commenting out MAPIUninitialize().
If I called MAPIToMIMEStm twice in the same session of MAPIInitialize() and MAPIUninitialize() then also this issue is reproduced.
    hr = pConverterSession->MAPIToMIMEStm(pMessage, pStream, flags); //Stream output 4285
    hr = pConverterSession->MAPIToMIMEStm(pMessage, pStream, flags); //Stream output 4228
The actual stream output is (4285 + 4228)=8513 instead of expected length(4285 + 4285)= 8570.

Comment: Hmmm... Where and how does your code run?

Comment: This native code is loaded into the JNI dll. The Java application service loads this JNI dll to extract messages of the .pst file in the form of .eml files. This code internally initializes the MAPI, login into the MAPI Session and get a message service administration object IMsgServiceAdmin to make changes to the message services in a profile. It then get the IMsgStore from the IMsgServiceAdmin to open the IMAPIFolder. The IMessages are extracted from the IMAPIFolder->OpenEntry() and then converted into the .eml files using MAPIToMIMEStm().

Comment: Does it work fro ma regular desktop app? I am surprised IConverterSession works for you - in Outlook 2016 and up it now only works if used in-proc (fro ma COM addin).

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. You are right. This code is working with Outlook 2013 for multiple requests but not with Outlook 2016. Also, the IConverterSession instance creation failed with Outlook 2019.  As you suggested, I will use the IConverterSession from a COM addin to fix this issue.

Comment: If this is an option, Redemption (I am its author) exposes MAPI <->MIME converter that works independently from IConverterSession.

Comment: Thanks. I will evaluate that option. Also, I observed that MAPIToMIMEStm() returns the different stream output when Outlook 2016 with Microsoft 365 was installed on my setup however when I uninstalled the Microsoft 365 and installed the Office professional plus 2016 setup again then MAPIToMIMEStm() started working fine for multiple requests. So it seems that this code is working with Outlook 2013, 2016 but not with 2019.

Comment: You can directly look at the MAPIToMIMEStm output in OutlookSpy (https://www.dimastr.com/outsp -I am also its author) - select an email, click IConverterSession, then MAPIToMIMEStm .